# C - struct in array (and a whole bunch of other problems)

Tags: c, arrays, struct, custom-data-type

I am a beginner in C. At the moment I'm learning about file handling in C, and I wanted to create a simple program that could read a text file and input the contents using a for loop.

Because I'm learning with a Pascal background in the back of my head, sometimes this gets quite confusing, especially with the new rules and syntax for structs and arrays

This is what my code (shortened down) looks like:

```
typedef struct {
    char *name;
    char *age;
} Person;
void write_lines_to_terminal(Person person_array[], int numberOfLines) {
   for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
    {
        printf("name: %s, age: %s\n", person_array[i].name, person_array[i].age);
    }
}

void read_lines_to_terminal(FILE *file_ptr) {
  my_string string;
  int i;
  int numberOfLines;
  fscanf(file_ptr, "%d", &numberOfLines);
  Person person_array[numberOfLines];
  for (i=0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
    fscanf(file_ptr, "%[^\n]\n", person_array[i].name);
    fscanf(file_ptr, "%[^\n]\n", person_array[i].age);
  }
  write_lines_to_terminal(person_array, numberOfLines);
 }
```

According to my Pascal logic, this should work. But apparently I got a whole bunch of errors revolving around -> and * and . that I couldn't understand. I tried searching answers on here but they didn't make sense to me....

Any help or suggestion to my code will be much appreciated.

EDIT: Added Person definition

Comment: " I got a whole bunch of errors revolving around" --> list those errors and any error messages.  Post definition of `my_string`, a [mcve]

Comment: Can you show the definition of the `Person` struct?

Comment: After `fscanf(file_ptr, "%d", &numberOfLines);` you need to read the newline to get to the next line.

Comment: Editing the question to add requested information is OK. Editing the question to significantly change some code is not OK. It makes all answers useless that address those parts of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fscanf()` doesn't return the value that was read, it returns the number of inputs that were successfully read. You have to provide pointers to the locations to store the inputs as arguments.

```
fscanf(file_ptr, "%[^\n]\n%[^\n]\n", person_array[i].name, person_array[i].age);
```

You also need to read past the newline after the number of lines before you start reading the data lines. Change that to:

```
fscanf(file_ptr, "%d\n", &numberOfLines);
```

Your `Person` structure has pointers in it, but you've never allocated any memory for them to point to. Instead you should use arrays:

```
typedef struct {
    char name[100];
    char age[4];
} Person;
```

I'm not sure why you're using a string for age instead of an `int`.

Comment: `"%[^\n]\n%[^\n]\n"` after `"%d"` may not scanf anything.

Comment: @Barmar After fixing up my code with your suggestion, all errors were gone, but the program crashed the moment I tried running it...

Comment: @Khang I'll bet your structure declaration is wrong, but you haven't posted it so we can't tell.

Comment: I'm using a string because it's in a text file that I'm reading from

Comment: So? `scanf()` can convert the text to an integer. You obviously know that, since you did that to read `numberOfLines`.

Comment: Trailing `\n` on the second fscanf format string is a mistake (it does not mean to match a newline). Instead you should read characters until you get a newline and then stop reading.  Also there are various other problems with the format string in the first suggestion ,and you should check the return value of scanf.

Comment: @M.M Isn't that what `%[^\n]` does?

Comment: @Barmar that string does not occur in the second fscanf format string.  Also, that specifier fails if it does not match. (So a blank line in the file will cause every read to fail and the program to output uninitialized buffers).

Comment: @M.M I'm trying to keep my answer simple, just address the basic misunderstandings.